# How many days pass during the first part of Konosuba episode 4?

Tags: konosuba

The first half of *Konosuba* episode 4 shows a montage of Kazuma and Megumin training, leading us to believe it went on for a long time.  Long enough for the seasons to change several times.

It seems to me that it wouldn't take too many for the event that happens halfway through the episode to happen, so I don't think it was a year like was implied with the changing of the seasons during the montage.

How many days has it been?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you look closely at that episode, Kazuma's explanation of the different setting was of weathers, not of seasons. *It was meant to show that they trained regardless of what weather it was during the day*. So, basically **only days passed, not seasons**.

To further reinforce this, **Volume 1 Chapter 3** of the light novel directly states how much time passed. To quote,

> Thus **we spent a week** in pleasant explosions. Then, one morning…

Comment: The snowfall seemed to indicate that there was a lengthy period of time elapsing.  Did I read too much into that?

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser Probably. There could be a number of reasons: possibilities include the one in charge of the animation probably overlook it, or they did not consult the author since they thought it was a pretty minor detail. In any case, the anime did not specify the time period whereas the LN did, so I think this is most likely a mistake in the animation part...

Comment: Or, for reasons not disclosed, they just changed that part deliberately. After all, anime adaptations tend to have differences from the source material itself, no matter how small they are...